# Detecting terminal command errors in Java

Tags: java, encryption, terminal, passwords

In my Java application I am using the `exec()` command to call a terminal function:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
p.waitFor();
```

The call uses the `zip` and `unzip` calls. Originally I call:

```
zip -P password -r encrypted.zip folderIWantToZip
```

When I call the `unzip` function through java, I specify the password as the method parameter. If the correct password is specified then the call should `unzip` the encrypted folder:

```
unzip -P password encrypted.zip
```

I want a way to find out if the password entered is incorrect. For example, if `password` is correct, then the call will correctly `unzip` the zip file. But I notice that no exception is thrown for an incorrect password. How can I determine this?

Comment: First thing I would do would be to capture the Process's InputStream and ErrorStream via `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()`, but especially the latter, the ErrorStream, and check to see what it outputs if the input is in error. These would have to be done in their own thread. Also, don't ignore the int returned by `p.waitFor()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the process's ErrorStream and InputStream to determine the process output. Sample code given below

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String command = "zip -P password -r encrypted.zip folderIWantToZip";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        int waitFor = p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));


        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("line:" + line);
        }
        is = p.getErrorStream();
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("ErrorStream:line: " + line);
        }
        System.out.println("waitFor:" + waitFor);
        System.out.println("exitValue:" + p.exitValue());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You could use the exitcode to validate the process status as well but it is specific to to program. Normally zero means successfully terminated otherwise abnormal termination.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, first thing I would do would be to capture the Process's InputStream and ErrorStream via getInputStream() and getErrorStream(), but especially the latter, the ErrorStream, and check to see what it outputs if the input is in error. Note that **these would have to be done in their own thread**, else you'll tie up your program. I usually use some type of StreamGobbler class for this. Also, don't ignore the int returned by p.waitFor().

e.g.,

```
  ProcessBuilder pBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(COMMAND);
  Process process = null;
  try {
     process = pBuilder.start();

     new Thread(new StreamGobbler("Input", process.getInputStream())).start();
     new Thread(new StreamGobbler("Error", process.getErrorStream())).start();

     int exitValue = process.waitFor();
     System.out.println("Exit Value: " + exitValue);
     process.destroy();


  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
     if (process != null) {
        process.destroy();
     }
  }
```

And:

```
class StreamGobbler implements Runnable {
   private String name;
   private Scanner scanner;

   public StreamGobbler(String name, InputStream inputStream) {
      this.name = name;
      scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
         String line = scanner.nextLine();
         System.out.println(name + ": " + line); // or better, log the line
      }
      scanner.close();
   }
}
```